# Inverse of the function $f(x) = e^x + \arctan(x) = y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Given the function

$$
f(x) = e^x + \arctan(x) = y\;,
$$

what is the inverse $f^{-1}(y)=\dots\;$, and how can I find it? 
I’m looking for solutions including all steps and possible explanations along with each.

To give some wider context, I bumped into this problem as part of a bigger question asking me to prove that $f(x)$ is bijective, $(f^{-1})'(y)$ exists for all $y>-\pi/2$ and to calculate $(f^{-1})'(y)$.

I have proven that $f$ is bijective and the rest of the properties follow from the applicability of the inversion theorem for derivatives, but I have a hard time calculating $(f^{-1})'(y)$ now because I can't find $(f^{-1})(y)$

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I didn’t change it in the edit, but I think that you mean $f^{-1}(y)=\dots\;$.

Comment: What is the domain and codomain of your function?

Comment: The fact that Wolfram Alpha only give a [numerical solution for $f(x)=0$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp%28x%29+%2B+atan%28x%29+%3D+0) suggests that there will not be a simple inverse

Comment: Added some more context, hope this helps

Comment: There is no elementary inverse function. Why do you need to find it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To find $(f^{-1})'(y)$ you don't need the inverse function. What you need is to use the inverse function theorem: if $f$ is injective and $f(x)=y$ then $(f^{-1})'(y)=\frac{1}{f'(x)}$.

Comment: [Inverse function theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem).

Comment: Ouch, thanks a lot!